# Indexing array using column names

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm loading pretty large input files into Numpy array (30 columns, over 10k rows). Data contains only floating point numbers. To simplify data processing I'd like to name columns and access them using human-readable names. AFAIK it's only possibly using structured/record arrays. However, if I'm right, when i use structured arrays I'll loose some information. For instance:

```
x = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4), (11, 22)], dtype='float64')
y = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4), (11, 22)], dtype=[('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)])
```

Both arrays contains the same data and the same dtype. y can be accessed using column names:

```
yIn [155]: y['x']
Out[155]: array([ 1.,  3., 11.])
```

Unfortunately, I loose (or I get wrong impression?) so essential properties when I use structured arrays. x and y have different shapes, y cannot be transposed etc.

```
In [160]: x
Out[160]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [11., 22.]])

In [161]: y
Out[161]: 
array([( 1.,  2.), ( 3.,  4.), (11., 22.)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])

In [162]: x.shape
Out[162]: (3, 2)

In [163]: y.shape
Out[163]: (3,)

In [164]: x.T
Out[164]: 
array([[ 1.,  3., 11.],
       [ 2.,  4., 22.]])

In [165]: y.T
Out[165]: 
array([( 1.,  2.), ( 3.,  4.), (11., 22.)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Is it possible to continue using "regular 2D Numpy arrays" and access columns using their names?

Comment: by column number would be easier. or you can view an array as a uniform dtype... verbosely, so you can pull it apart and see... y.view(np.float64).reshape(y.shape[0],2)

Comment: I don't know if it will fit your needs after, but using `pandas` DF such as `df = pd.DataFrame( x, columns=['x','y'])` then you can access the columns by names `df['x']` or use `df.T`. You can go back to "regular 2D NUmpy arrays" by `np.array(df['x'])` to do your operation using columns names, even if it's not especially necessary as you can use numpy function within `pandas`.

Comment: @Ben.T Right, I forgot to mention that. I consider pandas as my backup solution. First accessing panda's DataFrame is a bit slower than accessing Numpy array. Moreover it's additional dependency, that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: They have the same data, which you can verify by looking at their `.tobytes()`.  And they can be viewed as each other, e.g `x.view(y.dtype)` (though shapes get messed up a bit).

Comment: structured arrays make most sense when the fields have different dtypes, and you don't need to do 'math' across fields.  Sorting and indexing is fine.  But I wouldn't use them just for the convenience of using names instead of column numbers.

Comment: Perhaps keep a separate dictionary that maps column names to indices?

Comment: @Tai I tried that, but in long term it's not very handy solution (it makes code maintenance a bit harder). I look for more natural solution. Anyway your idea may be perceived as a workaround/solution.

Comment: Guess you can get all that you want... Maybe just stick to pandas and whenever performance matters, try `.values` to get the numpy representation of pandas dataframe to gain some speedup.